# No item selection in RecyclerView

Tags: android, mobile, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have made a vertical recyclerview in my program. When i click on any recyclerView items i don't see the on click listener working. Here is my code for the **Adapter class**:

```
class BoardItemsAdapter(private var list : ArrayList<Board>):RecyclerView.Adapter<BoardItemViewHolder>(){
private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BoardItemViewHolder {
        val from  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemBoardBinding.inflate(from , parent, false)
        return BoardItemViewHolder(parent.context, binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BoardItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindBoardItem(list[position])
    }
    interface OnClickListener : OnItemClickListener {
        fun onClick(position: Int, model: Board)
    }
    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener){
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }

}
```

**BoardItemViewHolder**:

```
class BoardItemViewHolder( private val context: Context, private val binding : ItemBoardBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bindBoardItem(list : Board){

// changing board name acording to database
        binding.tvBoardName.text = list.name
// using "Glide" 3rd party library to loading image for board image
Glide.with(context).load(list.image).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_board).into(binding.ivBoardImage)    
// changing owner of the board acording to database
        binding.tvCreatedBy.text = "Created by ${list.owner}"
    }

}
```

In my **MainActivity**:

```
/*
....
*/
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            val adapter = BoardItemsAdapter(boardsList)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            adapter.setOnClickListener(object: BoardItemsAdapter.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(position: Int, model: Board) {
                    startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, TaskList::class.java))
                }
            })
/*
....
*/
```

I thing something is wrong in **BoardItemsAdapter**, but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the onClick listener to items, you just store it inside the adapter.

```
class BoardItemsAdapter(private var list : ArrayList<Board>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BoardItemViewHolder>() {
    
    private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BoardItemViewHolder {
        val from  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemBoardBinding.inflate(from, parent, false)
        // Root is just an example.
        binding.root.setOnClickListener(this@BoardItemsAdapter.onClickListener)

        return BoardItemViewHolder(parent.context, binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BoardItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindBoardItem(list[position])
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener){
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }

}
```

```
class BoardItemViewHolder( private val context: Context, private val binding : ItemBoardBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bindBoardItem(list : Board){
        binding.tvBoardName.text = list.name
        Glide.with(context).load(list.image).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_board).into(binding.ivBoardImage)    
        binding.tvCreatedBy.text = "Created by ${list.owner}"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    fun bindBoardItem(list : Board, onClickListener: View.OnClickListener) {
        binding.tvBoardName.text = list.name
        Glide.with(context).load(list.image).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_board).into(binding.ivBoardImage)    
        binding.tvCreatedBy.text = "Created by ${list.owner}"
        binding.root.setOnClickListener(onClickLis)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BoardItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindBoardItem(list[position]) { this@BoardItemsAdapter.onClickListener(list[position]) }
    }
```

```
class BoardItemViewHolder(
    private val context: Context, 
    private val binding : ItemBoardBinding,
    private val onItemClickListener: BoardItemsAdapter.OnClickListener 
    private var item : Board
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    init {
        binding.root.setOnClickListener { onItemClickListener(item) }
    }
```

Comment: It is working but i want to use "model" parameters, with this when i implement members i just got a "View" parameter.

Comment: @Sina Well, yeah, that's why I showed an example and what wasn't working. Either store reference to the model in the view holder and reference it in the OnClick or update it with each binding of the ViewHolder with updated data from the adapter.